# I am trying to convert Java AES encryption decryption to NodeJs. This is what I have tried so far

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

Encryption:

```
private static String secretKey = "boooooooooom!!!!";
private static String salt = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
{
    try 
    {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Decryption:

```
private static String secretKey = "boooooooooom!!!!";
private static String salt = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) {
    try 
    {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have searched a lot about this. I got these questions on stack overflow

[Difference in key lengths between crypto.pbkdf2 (node.js) and PBEKeySpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332536/difference-in-key-lengths-between-crypto-pbkdf2-node-js-and-pbekeyspec), [AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING IV - Decryption in NodeJs (Encrypted in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922462/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-iv-decryption-in-nodejs-encrypted-in-java/50925146) I have tried both of them but none of them resolved my query.

What I have tried so far is,

```
function encrypt(plainText, secretKey,randomeString) {

    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secretKey, salt, 65536, 16, digest);
    const iv = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'base64')
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');      
    return encrypted;
};

function decrypt(strToDecrypt, secretKey, randomeString) {

    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secretKey, salt, 65536, 16, digest);

    const iv = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]);

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(strToDecrypt, 'base64');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Post your recent NodeJS-code.

Comment: @Topaco I was having key length problem before, I was using 16, 32 should be used, I used the same code as mentioned in question links.

Comment: @Topaco I have added my NodeJs code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Node.js code should produce the same results as your Java code. I also made the secretKey variable a parameter of the encrypt / decrypt functions.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const salt = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";
const digest = 'sha256';

function encrypt(plainText, secretKey) {

    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secretKey, salt, 65536, 32, digest);
    const iv = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'base64')
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
};

function decrypt(strToDecrypt, secretKey) {

    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secretKey, salt, 65536, 32, digest);
    const iv = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]);

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(strToDecrypt, 'base64');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
}

const key = "boooooooooom!!!!";
const cipherText = encrypt("test", key);
console.log("Ciphertext:", cipherText);
const plainText = decrypt(cipherText, key);
console.log("Plaintext:", plainText);
```